# Alternative to using HTML Select

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I have a HTML form with various SELECT (both multiline and drop down list style) elements. A number of the items in the SELECT are much wider than the element width. In most browsers it will display a tooltip and the drop down will be as wide as the widest option. In IE6 however neither of these work.

Does anyone know any alternative control, such as a jQuery plugin, that can be used as a SELECT replacement that will allow tooltips and wider drop down. It only needs to work in IE6.

Comment: "It only needs to work in IE6" - dont think i've EVER heard that statement before. =)

Comment: "It only needs to work in IE6." stunned. back to modern world, please.

Comment: "It only needs to work in IE6." - sounds like every other internal web application deployed in a corporate environment, and therefore a very valid question.

Comment: Should try to urge a progression in the company, to use a more modern technology. Can't think of ANY reason why people should still be building applications to ONLY work in IE6. It's just not right!

Comment: @Alex: this is easier said than done if you are working in a large corporation. imagine trying to move a beached whale back into the sea with simply a piece of brittle driftwood

Comment: WHen I say it only needs to work i IE6 that is because other browsers have the functionality built in I need.

Comment: If we asked GM to upgrade their browser, we'd be fired.  Out of a cannon.  Into the sun.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS to specify a width for the SELECT element that caters to your need.

```
select { width: 150px; }
```

Comment: The problem is that it is then to wide to fit on the page. I don't want the SELECT to be any wider, just the drop down portion of it.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of [jQuery Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/).

Here you get a selectable list of elements with a given width.  If you want something closer to a select menu (ie everything isn't listed out), you could take a look into a drop-down menu type implementation, and modify it to select your value instead of navigating to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE6, so I'm not 100% if you can set the width of a `select` element. If you can't, you could just 'recreate' a select element. I wouldn't be surprised if IE6 had some issue with it.

For example, create  a `display: inline-block` `div` for each option, then loop through each div and get the highest width. Loop through again and set each width to the highest width. Keep these in one unique container (with the same width to ensure they wrap) and position them next to an element created for this purpose. Not sure how practical it is for your application, but heh.

To elaborate, this is what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/Svkxc/